# How to manage canary version bump in monorepo with lerna from different branches

Tags: typescript, monorepo, tagging, lerna

Let's assume we've got typescript project with monorepo structure and lerna as a tool for versioning and publishing packages. We have to implement two different changes but both are affecting one package.
At the begginig we have package `foo@1.0.0`. One developer had implemented feat on his branch (dev-foo) and want to test it. Using:

`lerna version --include-merged-tags --conventional-prerelease`

lerna will bump version of package `foo` to `foo@1.1.0-alpha.0`, commit prerelease and push it to origin.

At the same time another dev did the second change on his own branch (dev-bar) and wants to prerelease his changes. Using command above lerna would attempt to bump version on package `foo@1.0.0` also to `foo@1.1.0-alpha.0` but the command will fail because tag `foo@1.1.0-alpha.0` already exists.
It happens after `git fetch` also.

How to prevent such behaviour? Suitable solution would be to bump such versions to `foo@1.1.0-alpha.0` and `foo@1.1.0-beta.0`. How to achieve that?

How to prevent lerna from bumping package version to one already existed but not merged? Like canary version bumped on dev-foo branch? In another words - how to support independent development and prerelase tagging of the same workspace?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `lerna publish --canary --preid beta` to get the tag as mentioned in the lerna doc it self.

--preid
Unlike the lerna version option of the same name, this option only applies to --canary version calculation.

```
lerna publish --canary
# uses the next semantic prerelease version, e.g.
# 1.0.0 => 1.0.1-alpha.0

lerna publish --canary --preid next
# uses the next semantic prerelease version with a specific prerelease identifier, e.g.
# 1.0.0 => 1.0.1-next.0
```

When run with this flag, lerna publish --canary will increment premajor, preminor, prepatch, or prerelease semver bumps using the specified prerelease identifier.